# confused by interaction between function parameter, closures, and scope chain

Tags: javascript, variables, closures

The code in question:

```
    function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function (num) {
            return function () {
                alert(num);
            };
        }(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
  }
  window.onload = addLinks;
```

My problem is since the returned function is a closure and variable `num` is the global variable each time the function executes `num` should hold the current value replacing the old one and should automatically update with that value everywhere.  But this isn't happening -- when I click each link I get a different value.  Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Executing first version of `addLinks` in console and then clicking the links it adds results in each time a different value is alerted. Is this unexpected behaviour for you?

Comment: @Marcell Fülöp yaa completely unexpected as num is a global variable and its value should change or  update each time the function runs

Comment: @Maizere num is not global.  You don't need the `var` keyword when defining function parameters - they are implicitly local to that function.

Comment: @Marcell Fülöp thanks for the info.i thought num is a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it: what if you had three links like so:

```
<a href="#">0</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
```

You want them to alert out their number when you click on them, so you do it like this:

```
var links = $('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[0].onclick = function () {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

At first glance, you'd expect that, for example, since you assigned the click handler on the first link when `i = 0`, it'll alert `0` when you click it. However when you click it, it'll actually alert `3`.

You said it yourself, your code is creating a closure. What the code above does is that it's assigning a function handler to the click event of each link. Each of those function handlers is maintaining a reference to the variable `i` (note: not it's current value!).

At the point when you assign the function handler, it actually doesn't evaluate what value `i` has (because it doesn't need it). When you click, aha, that's when it checks what value `i` has and alerts it.

By the time you click a link, your `for` loop will be long finished, with `i = 3`, and that's what your click handler alerts.

Answer (score 2):

`num` is closed over by the anonymous function.  The `function (num) { return function () {}}(i)` passes `i` as it is to the inner function and returns a new function based on whatever `i`'s value is at the time.

If you want the click callback to always alert the maximum value of `i`, it's actually even easier:

```
link.onclick = function () {
    alert(i);
}
```

`function (var varname)` is simply invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the (i) after your function. This type of notation is for self-invocating functions only. It's as if you are setting link.onclick = a number, whereas it expects a function. You can simply use the following.

```
    link.onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(i);
    };
```

Please note that click functions receive the "event" as a parameter by default. Make sure you call the preventDefault() method of the event otherwise it will bubble up the DOM and trigger a postback due to the nature of the anchor element.

Comment: what are u telling ,u are out of the topic sir

Comment: "It's as if you are setting link.onclick = a number" no it's not -- it's setting it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained where the variable `num` has come from or how it's used. I'm guessing you mean to alert the current value of `i`. The click handler takes an event object as a parameter so I would try it like this:

```
function addLinks () {
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
    link.onclick = function (event) {
            alert(i);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

Comment: HTML elements do not have a `.on` method.

Comment: Yes you're right -- got jQuery mixed up in this. My apologies. So you could switch it back link.onclick = function(event) { alert(i); };

Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is strange and disagrees with what I thought to knew about closures. With the only change (in the first version of `addLinks` in the question):

```
link.onclick = function (num)
```

to

```
link.onclick = function ()
```

You get the expected result, that is, the actual value of the global `num` variable is alerted any time when a link is clicked.

It probably has to do with how the interpreter saves scope variables that are referenced within a closure when it encounters that closure. When a variable is referneced in a closure, the closest occurrence of that variable is searched for going upwards from the current scope.

While in the first case it is defined as a parameter (to the function that is *called* after declaration multiple times) it has different value each time so a different scope value is "remembered" by each closure.

In the 2nd case, the only occurrence found is in the global scope which results in the actual value of `num` is being used regardless which handler is called.